# New Properties Not Populated in C# App with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a C# app that uses the Entity Framework. I need to add a couple of properties to a Result. I have successfully added the properties at the database level. I have confirmed that they are part of the result set I get from the database. However, I need to get those new properties onto the model in C#.

At this time, I have the following:

```
public ObjectResult<Result> GetResult(int resultID)
{
  return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<GetResult>("GetResult", resultID);
}
```

That code work(ed). However, my new properties are not getting populated and I cannot figure out why. In the database, the new properties are of type:

```
int
float
datetime
```

In code, I've added the following properties to the `Result` class.

```
    public Nullable<int> Length { get; set; }

    public Nullable<float> Average { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
```

When I view the result in the watch window, I notice the following values for the new properties:

```
null
null
{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}
```

Its like the new properties are not getting set. I do not understand why this would happen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the properties are mapped to columns? Open up the designer (if you're doing DB first approach) and make sure you have the mappings set up correctly.

Comment: Well, when I run ```SELECT name, system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object
(
  OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[MyStoredProcedureName]'), 
  NULL
);``` I can see the new columns listed.

Comment: Yes, but are they actually mapped to your `Result` object?

Comment: did you find any solution for this. I have added a new column in the result set and change the model to accomodate the model, but still I am getting null  for the newly added property.